# Webpack dynamic require gives Mixed Content error

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying out Webpacks dynamic require which turns whatever I require into a dynamic module and splits off the code.

```
import(`resources/assets/images/svg/${this.name}.svg`).then((module) => {
    this.svg = module;
}).catch(error => 'An error occured while loading the svg');
```

The code is then being injected into the page with a script tag when the promise fires. Except the script tag is using `http` instead of `https`.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://test.app' was loaded over HTTPS,
>   but requested an insecure script 'http://test.app/28.js'. This request
>   has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How can I make sure that my dynamic require uses `https`. Is this a setting I can tweak in my webpack configuration?

**Update:**

It it not an http or https issue rather Webpack create a script tag without a / prefix:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" src="22.js"></script>
```

This results in scripts being resolved to:

> mywebpage.app/test/22js

While it actually needs to be:

> mywebpage.app/22.js

I don't know to how to solve this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using:

```
output: {
    publicPath: '/'
}
```

I hope this does not clash with anything else though.